# How to join 2nd list with first list based on a field in 1st list?

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8

I have 2 lists, the 1st list contains a field that can be duplicated and seconds list contain the same field without duplicate with other fields. What I need is to join the two list to one based on that common field.

List 1 :

```
[
{
    "id" : "1"
    "name : "hello",
    "item_name": "Name"

},
{
    "id" : "1"
    "name : "hi"
    "item_name": "Name2"

},
{
    "id" : "2"
    "name : "hello"
    "item_name": "Name"

}
]
```

Second List :

```
[{
    "id" : "1"
    "age" :  "10",
    "place" : "0",
    "date" : "0"
},
{
    "id" : "2"
    "age" :  "12",
    "place" : "1",
    "date" : "0
}]
```

Expected Result :

```
[
    {
            "id" : "1"
            "name : "hello",
            "item_name": "Name",
            **"age" :  "10",
            "place" : "0",
            "date" : "0**
    },
    {
            "id" : "1"
            "name : "hi"
            "item_name": "Name2"
            **"age" :  "10",
            "place" : "0",
            "date" : "0"**
    },
    {
            "id" : "2"
            "name : "hello"
            "item_name": "Name"
            **"age" :  "12",
            "place" : "1",
            "date" : "0"**
    }
    ]
```

Bold areas are joined from the second list
Please help in this

I have tried :

```
Map<String, String> listMap = list2
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(List1Entity::getId,
                    List1Entity::getId));
    list1.forEach(a -> {
        a.setPlace(listMap.get(a.getId()));
    });
```

But getting error at .collect(),

> no instances or type variable exist so that List2Entity conforms to
>   List1Entity

Comment: In some sense sounds like 1 is a `List` and 2 is a `Set`. If that could improve what you're trying out. Do share what gets you stuck and the entities in the question.

Comment: @Naman, No both are a list of objects

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean `List2Entity` in the first statement?

```
Map<String, String> listMap = list2
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(List2Entity::getId,
                List2Entity::getPlace));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are a bit unclear when it comes to define the joining part between the two lists.

You can start with something like this and adapt `mapFunction` to your needs.

```
String list1 = "[{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"hello\",\"item_name\":\"Name\"},{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"hi\",\"item_name\":\"Name2\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"hello\",\"item_name\":\"Name\"}]";
String list2 = "[{\"id\":\"1\",\"age\":\"10\",\"place\":\"0\",\"date\":\"0\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"age\":\"12\",\"place\":\"1\",\"date\":\"0\"}]";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Map<String, Object>> l1 = mapper.readValue(list1, new TypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>>(){});
List<Map<String, Object>> l2 = mapper.readValue(list2, new TypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>>(){});

final UnaryOperator<Map<String, Object>> mapFunction = map -> {
    final String id = map.get("id").toString();
    l2.stream()
        .filter(map2 -> map2.get("id").toString().equals(id))
        .findAny()
        .ifPresent(map::putAll);
    return map;
};

List<Map<String, Object>> result = l1
        .stream()
        .map(mapFunction)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Joining part is as mentioned in the question, i.e 1st list does not contain some fields, while the second list has those fields, Join the parameters from the second list to the first list for the ids in common. I hope you get that